What kind of fire alarm in a detached backyard office?
I have a 96sqft detached finished shed in my backyard which I use as an office. I don't have any kind of fire alarm right now, and I'm trying to decide whether and what kind I need.
No one ever sleeps here.
There are no significant valuables here.
No workshop, welding, etc. just a computer, but I do have a space heater and window AC.
It's about 4' from the house, and there are tree branches above/around it.
Should I:

Do nothing.
Get a normal dumb smoke alarm ($20ish). I don't think I'd hear it from most of the house.
Get some wireless interconnected smoke alarms, put one here, and one in the house nearby ($100ish). This would also be an grade for the home because all the smoke alarms in the house are dumb. It's 1500sqft, though, and I can generally hear them all from everywhere.

Thank you!

Have you made sure that the house wall adjacent to the shed and the inside of the shed adjacent to the house are finished using 5/8" Type X drywall? (That'll help at least somewhat in keeping the shed fire from becoming a house fire, as well as making sure there aren't windows looking right out onto that 4' gap between the house and the shed from either building)

If you are going to invest time and money in installing connected detectors, in this decade, you may as well get a basic smart burglar alarm system like Simplisafe or Ring.  A little more money up front but the time and effort of installing anything makes the extra money worthwhile for the extra functionality and expandability.   You can put a door sensor on the office, and a water sensor on the floor, etc.  You can sign up for monitoring if you want, or you can just have it notify your phone if something is wrong.   You can put the main hub in the main house, and you can add things in the house like water sensors near A/Cs and toilets etc.  You don't have to do any of this now, you can just start with a very basic system built around the smoke alarm in the office.
If you want to avoid internet-connected things (because even if you don't subscribe for monitoring you rely on the mother ship for much functionality) you can do something similar with Z-Wave smoke detectors and a Z-Wave hub that will notify your phone, ring bells or alarms, or whatever you want.

Thank you! I'll look into this.

There are two separate issues here:

Alert Occupants

That is the only purpose of a "normal dumb" smoke alarm. Not unreasonable even in a one-room building on the off chance that someone could fall asleep in a desk chair with a space heater running. $20 and you're done.
Interconnected helps with this in a large home as a fire in the basement could easily spread very quickly to the bedrooms two floors up. While I see no significant gain in connecting an outbuilding's smoke/fire detection to the main building if it is far away (we get questions here about voltage drop from buildings 300' apart) since this is only 4' away it is practically the same building. Which means that if you bother to install interconnected in the main building then you should include the shed as well in that same group.

Alert the Fire Department

This is required in large commercial buildings and multi-tenant residential buildings in many areas. It is generally not required in single-family homes. If you go down this path then you will get into a usually very heavily regulated area. Typically, but not always, requirements include:

Notify a monitoring company rather than the fire department directly, but this will vary by jurisdiction
Installation (wiring, central equipment, smoke/fire detectors) follows specific rules and possibly with special inspections as part of the installation process
Periodic (e.g., quarterly or annual) inspections
Backup power for the system
Dedicated communications for the system (wired phone line or possibly a cellular or internet based system)
Installation (wiring, central equipment, smoke/fire detectors) follows specific rules and possibly with special inspections as part of the installation process

Basically a lot of work and expense, which is why it generally is only done where required, which is generally big buildings.

I am generally not in favor of wireless interconnections for safety or other vital equipment. The chances of interference are non-zero, particularly since most consumer-grade systems share a few frequency chunks with a lot of other stuff - cordless phones, WiFi, etc. Wired also has the advantage that power comes from the wire with battery only as backup.

I think your final paragraph is outdated.   Modern battery-operated wireless detectors are cheap, they are easy to install, the battery lasts 6 to 10 years, and they are not passive, they send heartbeats and low-battery messages to their hubs and nag you when they need care.  They may not pass every test of a commercial system but they far exceed in performance what a homeowner can buy and install with a wired system for 10 times the price.

@jay613 You may be right. Key is a heartbeat - if they really do that right then intermittent interference and other problems are not a big deal.

My Honeywell detectors all alarm if I remove the cover, if I bang them (they have vibration sensors), and if I remove the battery which is to say the hub misses them very quickly,  I don't know if Simplisafe, Ring, or others are that sophisticated and it's good you raised the question.   OP should set the bar.   Low battery is a no brainer but no battery is a very important one.

The outbuilding 4 feet away from the main structure catching fire is not that different from a fire in the basement - something bad is likely going to happen soon to the main structure without attention being paid.

@JonCuster I missed that it is only 4' away - that makes a huge difference.

Thank you all! I'm going to go with a wireless interconnect system.
